# issue with Biguqery Stored procedure

Tags: google-bigquery

```sql
create or replace procedure Practise.sp_test()
OPTIONS(strict_mode=false)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_product_code int64;
DECLARE v_price int64;

    set v_product_code = (SELECT product_code FROM `virendra101987.Practise.product` where v_product_code =01);
    set v_price = (SELECT price FROM `virendra101987.Practise.product` where v_product_code =01);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_product_code;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_price;

    insert into `Practise.sales1`(order_date,product_code,quantity_order,sales_price)
    values (current_date(),v_product_code,1,v_price);

    END


   CALL `virendra101987.Practise.sp_test`();
```

Why am I getting this error?

`ERROR Query error: Cannot coerce expression v_product_code to type STRING at [virendra101987.Practise.sp_test:7:23]`

Answer (score 0):

The error message arises from the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` expecting a string.  However in looking at what you're trying to achieve I don't believe it is necessary.
The `SET` operator will execute the SQL statements for you and does not require any further action to evaluate.  So you should be able to pass them into your insert statement without issue.

For example:

```
create or replace procedure Practise.sp_test()
OPTIONS(strict_mode=false)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_product_code int64;
DECLARE v_price int64;

    set v_product_code = (SELECT product_code FROM `virendra101987.Practise.product` where v_product_code =01);
    set v_price = (SELECT price FROM `virendra101987.Practise.product` where v_product_code =01);


    insert into `Practise.sales1`(order_date,product_code,quantity_order,sales_price)
    values (current_date(),v_product_code,1,v_price);

    END;


   CALL `virendra101987.Practise.sp_test`();
```

Comment: I tried without Execute immediate but in sales 1 table the variable data is showing null.

Comment: can you confirm that your queries for v_product_code and v_price individually produce your expected values?